# CountDownLatch in Java need additional synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, countdownlatch

Let's say I have the code below:

```
public class CountDownLatchExample {  // Note : Exception handling ommited
    void main(){
        CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(N_PARTIES);
        for(int i = 0; i < N_PARTIES; i++){ // create and start threads
            new Thread(() -> {
                startSignal.await();    // Wait startSignal before doing Work
                doWork();
                doneSignal.countDown();
            }).start();
        }
        // (...) do something else              // Don't let run yet
        startSignal.countDown();                // Let all threads proceed
        // (...) do something else
        doneSignal.await();                     // Wait for all threads to finish
    }
}
```

The *main* thread creates and starts the worker threads. In the `run` method, the other threads wait until the *main* thread call `startSignal.countDown()`, and then they can call `doWork()` and d`oneSignal.countDown()`.

I know that there is an happens-before relationship between the `countDown()` called by a thread and threads that return from `await`, then if a thread call `doneSignal.countDown()`, what it did is visible to all the other threads.

But my question is if the `run()` method is executed sequentially or not, and if we need to add synchronization??

Because when `startSignal.countDown()` is called, all the threads can execute the `run` method, but suppose that in the `doWork()` method there are some shared variables that change, or also simply that executing `run()` concurrently, there are maybe three threads that executed `doWork()` concurrently, and then two of them are scheduled out right before doneSignal.countDown(), and the third one call doneSignal.countDown(). Here the happens-before relationship is a little bit useless if the other two threads have already executed doWork() and they have only to call doneSignal.countDown(), because they didn't see what the third one did, because they executed doWork() "together".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CountDownLatch` does not  guarantee *per* the [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) of the accesses to the share data, rather this mechanism is used to synchronized -- in the sense of one waiting for the other -- parallel task among each other. Similar to the functionality provided by a [Cyclic barrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). Actually, as you have described this is the reason why you are using this mechanism in your code; to coordinate the execution of the *main* and the remaining threads.

If the doWork() method contains shared state among threads, which is modified concurrently, then you might have *race-condition*. Hence, you need to ensure mutual exclusion of that shared using for instance the *synchronized* clause.